# How to use firebase Dynamic Link with flutter go_route package

Tags: flutter, firebase-dynamic-links, flutter-navigation, gorouter

in firebase doc they call  FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink() in main funtion but with go route   can i call it main funtion and how to handle initialLink

where i call getInitialLink() !!

```dart
  Future<void> fBdynamicLink() async {
    // Get any initial links
    final PendingDynamicLinkData? initialLink =
        await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();

    if (initialLink != null) {
      debugPrint('initialLink ${initialLink.toString()}');
      final Uri deepLink = initialLink.link;
      // Example of using the dynamic link to push the user to a different screen
      context.push(deepLink.path);
    }
  }
```